# Covert image to custom folium tile/map

Tags: python, folium

I want to add the below image as my map on folium. When I create a link to this image and use it as a tile, the image gets tiled instead of just being a single instance. I followed the same steps as shown [here](https://melaniewalsh.github.io/Intro-Cultural-Analytics/07-Mapping/02-Custom-Maps.html) where they replace the map with a Game of Thrones map.

[image]

I tried to play around with the input arguments such as location, max bounds, min & max for lat & long and the crs but to no avail. The only idea i thought of but didn't try was to convert my image into a tile object (because I have no clue how to). Any help to fix this will be nice! Images from my unsuccessful codes are below. In both cases, I get a heatmap (albeit a different one) but it is not aligned with the map and the map is tiled.

[image][image]

**Context and Code**

I have several thousand routes that are executed and I want to visualise a heatmap of the paths taken by a vehicle to identify sections of the map that are commonly traversed. I want to superimpose these routes onto my image/map.

```
import folium
import pandas as pd

routes = [[(61.0, 37.0), (53.0, 5.0), (1.0, 49.0), (23.0, 43.0), (25.0, 39.0), (61.0, 37.0)], 
[(61.0, 37.0), (93.0, 57.0), (29.0, 73.0), (23.0, 71.0), (15.0, 67.0), (53.0, 35.0), (61.0, 37.0)], 
[(61.0, 37.0), (53.0, 35.0), (61.0, 37.0)], [(61.0, 37.0), (67.0, 45.0), (93.0, 57.0), (85.0, 69.0), (79.0, 71.0), (61.0, 37.0)], 
[(61.0, 37.0), (23.0, 71.0), (13.0, 75.0), (15.0, 67.0), (23.0, 43.0), (53.0, 5.0), (61.0, 37.0)]]

m = folium.Map(max_bounds=True,
           min_lon=1.0, max_lon=97, min_lat=3, max_lat=99,
           tiles='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1yT3yuk2w6HW6MG8uWGJohBqTicULwQ9d',
           attr='T',
           crs='Simple')

for rr in routes:
    folium.PolyLine(rr, color = 'red',  weight=1, opacity=1).add_to(m)
```